# Js. display array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have response from server:

```
response: {
    count: 100,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        from_id: 999,
        date: 1394397408,
        text: 'aaa'
        }, {
        id: 2,
        from_id: 9999,
        date: 1394397419,
        text: 'bbb'
    }]
}
```

I use this way to display data:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.response.items.length; i++) { alert(data.response.items[i].id); }
```

But i think, that this is bad-practice, are there another ways to get all ids to variable/alert? Objects are difficult for me in this step of my js-education.

Comment: What makes you think that looping over an array is bad practise?

Comment: Dont worry. Iterating over arrays is ok

Comment: I think that using things like map/forEach/some/every etc is cleaner when applicable (and supported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd press F12, and paste this:

```
data.response.items.map(function(it) { return it.id })
```

assuming that `data` is inside a closure, I'd either do something like `window.dbgData = data`, and do my debugging with it, or put a breakpoint inside the function. At least in the chrome debugger, local variables are accessible from the console, when on a breakpoint.

At the end of the day the way you do it is completely up to you. I also use `alert` from time to time.

Comment: If it's of any help, there where mismatched brackets/parentheses in your snippet.